# Hybrid Table data structure in JAVA

Tags: java

In C# world, we devised a intelligent table structure that looked like an vector, but it had a smart caching implemented. Lets take a below table example

```
Symbol Bid Ask Volume
AAPL   600 601 19292
MSFT   30  31  93939
```

There are 4 fields in above table structure, and users were able to access columns and rows using standard reader notation such as Table.AAPL[0], Table.Bid[0], Table.count etc.

What we did is implemented a smart caching strategies, lets say if there are 10 million rows in database, the table use to load only 1000 rows in memory, but when user accesed 1001 element then we use to swap the current rows from memory and fetch next 1000 rows from database and cache it. Our goal was to cache only 1000 rows at any time, but give user the experience of a array navigation technique.

I want to know if there are any open source frameworks that allows me such capabilities, before i go and start porting my C# code.